# Using item counter in conditional in definition of item label (xetex)

Tags: enumerate

I'm making an `enumerate` list, and I'd like to get the label to depend on the value of the counter, specifically by adding a space before the beginning if I'm above 9. That's because my label would be `[label={\upshape N˚ \arabic"}]`, and keeping it like that would mean that from 10 on the label is moved to the left and goes beyond the left-hand margin of my page. I would use `\ifnum<sth>>9\,\,\else \fi`, only I don't know what to put in `<sth>` to have the numbered list's number as the test expression. I guess an `enumerate` defines a counter for items. How do I use its value?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

This code should do what you want (if not, adapt it to your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength{\templength}
\settowidth{\templength}{1}

\newcommand{\numspace}{%
  \ifnum\value{enumi}<10%
  N°\hspace{\templength}%
  \else%
  N°%
  \fi
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\protect\numspace~\arabic*}]
  \item aaa
  \item aaa
  \item aaa
  \item aaa
  \item aaa
  \item aaa
  \item aaa
  \item aaa
  \item aaa
  \item aaa
  \item aaa
  \item aaa
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]